How Import xml file in music
I have a folder containing the xml files of playlists exported from itunes. How do I automatically import them into music with a script?

Did you try to import in Music by going to menubar File → Import?

Yes, of course. Except I have 238 playlists! I would like to automate the whole process with a script that I don't know how to do. Thank you

Instead of exporting single playlists, exporting your complete library as XML should be much easier. File → Export → Export Library...

It doesn't work when switching from iTunes to Music

The first step with automation is to manually perform the action to be sure it works. I’m going to assume you haven’t done any research (if that’s a bad assumption, please edit your question to show the research). I’m also going to assume you don’t have any script started, no language you prefer or use and no research on that either.

Back up your Mac and make sure you have time to restore if needed.
Try importing two manually and see that you get the results you expect.
Borrow from well documented and respected script libraries.


https://dougscripts.com/itunes/index.php

Doug has some playlist scripts that will help if you need to ask a follow on question with enough details for us to help you over any challenges.

I created a keyboard shortcut for "import playlist" If I press the corresponding keys, it works. Doug's script doesn't have, or at least I haven't found, a script to automatically import xml files in sequence and, as I wrote at the beginning, I don't know where to start compiling a script. Otherwise I wouldn't have asked you.

Hello and Welcome to Ask Different. We love people who don’t know and something’s just saying that plainly helps us engage with you at the level you need. Please don’t take offense of “lack of research” we try to be constructive with any request for details.

For chaining together several scripts you’ve got https://redsweater.com/fastscripts/ and Keyboard Maestro to consider if you don’t want to use Automator to repeat keystrokes for several files you feed into the automation.

If I had known how to do it, I wouldn't have asked here. Anyway thanks for the precious help


Copy the ITL file (not XML) from your old iTunes database
Hold down the OPTION key while opening the Music App → Select your ITL file.

